# Is a harmonic function in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)$ equal to zero?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let $u :\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth harmonic function ($\Delta u = 0$). Furthermore, suppose that $u \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)$, with $1 < p < \infty$. Does it follow that $u = 0$ everywhere?

By the theorem of Liouville, this follows immediately if $u \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$. For $u \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)$, this would also follow if we knew that $u$, for example, is uniformly continuous ($u$ is necessarily unbounded, find a sequence of points $x_k$ such that $u(x_k) \to \infty$, and apply the definition of uniform continuity in a neighbourhood of those points to get a contradiction with $u \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)$).

The enemy seems therefore higher and narrower ``spikes'' going off to infinity. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Also $u\in L^p$ can be seen as a tempered distribution. Each harmonic tempered distribution is a harmonic polynomial. In particular, $u$ is a polynomial. But every $L^p$-polynomial is equal to $0$. So $u=0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may settle it:

By the mean value property, we have, leting $r >0$,
$$
|u(x)| \leq \frac 1 {\pi r^2} \int_{B_r(x)} |u(y)| \ d y.
$$
Using H\"older on the RHS, we have
$$
\frac 1 {\pi r^2} \int_{B_r(x)} |u(y)| \ d y \leq \frac 1 {{\pi}^{1-1/q}} r^{-2 + 2/q} \|u \|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)}.
$$ Where $1/q + 1/p =1$. Hence $-2+2/q = -2/p$. Then send $r \to \infty$.

Comment: That's it. However, applying Hölder I obtain $\frac1{r^2}\int_{B_r(x)}|u|\le C \|u\|_p r^{-\frac2p}$. This is better because it also gives $p=1$. Can you check the computation?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the exponent in my formula is $-2 +2/q$, where $q$ is the dual exponent. Thank you!